# Problem about machine learning regression

Tags: machine-learning

I have to predict the weight of fishes in a database. With "mae" i have to improve getting less than 10..but I dont know what kind of optimizer i have to use for improve the "mae"..

159 fishes in database
7 attributes (species, Lenght1, Lenght 2, Lenght 3, Height, Width.
Training set -- 143 instances
Validation set --- 16 instances

**Full code:**

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/G2/Fish.csv', header=0)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
y=df['Weight']
x=df.drop(columns=['Weight'])

#Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)

from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu',
                           input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae']) #MSE = Mean Square Error / MAE = Mean Absolute Error
    return model

from keras import optimizers


model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', 
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['mae'])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor= 'mae', mode='min', patience = 100, verbose=1)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('/content/model_regression.h5', monitor='mae', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
history = model.fit(x_train,
                    y_train,
                    epochs=150,
                    batch_size=10,
                    callbacks = [es, mc])
```

**Final Result:**
Epoch 00150: mae did not improve from 29.04137  ------> The number I get is 29, i have to improve this in less than 10

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What else did you try. Neural nets are probably a overkill here. Did you check random forest etc?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/88714/64377. @Michael Please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: Hi!, not really but in the last question a couldnt be more specific, i will continue with the ideas I received